# Code not working. It takes an eternity to run

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle10g

The code below runs for an eternity. 
As you can see i have to take values from one table and use that value to check if the second table contains it or not and insert into the third table values from the first table.
Is there any other way of doing this?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE KPI_AVAILABILITY (
    v_programid varchar2
    )
AS 
         v_MASTER_KPI_ID number;
         v_UDF varchar2(100);
         v_count number;

    cursor c1 is 
       (select MASTER_KPI_ID,UDF from KPI_MASTER 
        where UDF is not null
        and ISACTIVE = 1
        --order by MASTER_KPI_ID,udf
       );

BEGIN
  open c1 ;
  fetch c1 into v_MASTER_KPI_ID,v_UDF;

  while v_UDF is not null
  loop
     select count(v_UDF) into v_count 
     from vw_ticket 
     where v_UDF is not null
     and amsprogramid = v_programid;
     if v_count is not null or v_count <> 0 then
           delete from program_kpi where amsprogramid = v_programid;
           INSERT INTO PROGRAM_KPI (AMSPROGRAMID,MASTER_KPI_ID,LASTUPDATEDBYDATALOAD) 
            VALUES(V_PROGRAMID,v_MASTER_KPI_ID,to_char(sysdate,'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss')); 
            dbms_output.put_line('xyz');
        end if;
    end loop;
    close c1;

END KPI_AVAILABILITY;
```

Comment: YOu need to show some sample data and the desired result. It is not possible to infer that from your code.

Comment: This expression is redundant and probably wrong: `v_count is not null or v_count <> 0` - if v_count is not null, the preceding query guarantees it will be nonzero. Why not simply use `v_count > 0`?

Comment: Performance-wise, you should merge the subquery on `vw_ticket` into the cursor query to reduce the amount of work required, and reduce context switches.

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on `program_kpi.amsprogramid`? If so, you could replace the delete+insert with a single merge statement; which would then remove the need for the separate cursor and loop entirely, you can do the whole operation in one single SQL statement.

Comment: Is `LASTUPDATEDBYDATALOAD` a `DATE` or `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: In that case you should not call `to_char` when inserting sysdate into it.

Comment: that works in other procedures. It inserts too.

Comment: @Olivia, it may work for **you today**, but it depends on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` matching the format string you use in `to_char`, because sql has to take the string from `to_char` and convert it back to a date, that is being done implicitly. Also you are converting to 12 hour time with no AM/PM. So everything will be transferred to the morning?

Answer (score 3):

Reverse engineering business rules from another developer's code is always tricky, especially without understanding the wider domain.  However, at the centre of the loop is DELETE from `program_kpi` followed by an INSERT into the same table.  If there are no records matching on `amsprogramid = v_programid` then you're inserting a record, if there are matches then effectively you're just *updating* `lastupdatedbydataload` with the current SYSDATE.

In others, it appears to be the logic of a MERGE.  So perhaps your code could be entirely replaced with a single statement. If so, this is likely to be a lot more efficient than the row-by-agonizing-row process within a cursor loop.

```
merge into program_kpi pkpi
using (select kpim.master_kpi_id
              , kpim.udf 
              , v_programid
       from kpi_master kpim
        where kpim.udf is not null
        and kpim.isactive = 1
        and exists ( select null 
                      from vw_ticket tkt
                      where tkt.amsprogramid = v_programid)
       ) kpim
on (kpim.v_programid = pkpi.programid
    and kpim.master_kpi_id = pkpi.master_kpi_id)
when not matched then
    insert values (kpim.v_programid, kpim.master_kpi_id, sysdate)
when matched then
    update 
    set pkpi.lastupdatedbydataload = sysdate;
```

Please check the results of this code with your expected outcome.  As I said, reverse-engineering business logic is hard, and matching on `master_kpi_id` as well as  `programid` is not the same as just deleting on `programid`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not change v_UDF after first fetch. Then loop compare it with same first value... compare and compare... compare and compare.